# Javascript CSV export with BOM charset

Tags: javascript, html, excel

So I have my function like below and would like to see if I am able to convert the default charset to BOM upon generation, I would like to solve the garbled code problem in excel.

```
 exportCSVFile(headers, items, fileTitle) {
          if (headers) {
              items.unshift(headers);
          }
            // console.log(items)
          // Convert Object to JSON
          var jsonObject = JSON.stringify(items);
          var csv = this.convertToCSV(jsonObject);

          var exportedFilenmae = fileTitle + '.csv' || 'export.csv';

          var blob = new Blob([csv], { type: 'text/csv;charset=windows-1252;' });
          if (navigator.msSaveBlob) { // IE 10+
              navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, exportedFilenmae);
          } else {
              var link = document.createElement("a");
              if (link.download !== undefined) { // feature detection
                  // Browsers that support HTML5 download attribute
                  var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                  link.setAttribute("href", url);
                  link.setAttribute("download", exportedFilenmae);
                  link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
                  document.body.appendChild(link);
                  link.click();
                  document.body.removeChild(link);
              }
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution would be, adding BOM with UTF8

```
var blob = new Blob(["\uFEFF"+csv], {
type: 'text/csv; charset=utf-18'
});
```